# How do I determine x for the following problems

Tags: logarithms, radicals

I have to put the ranges where the following exists:
$$\sqrt[6-x^2]x$$
I put the condition that
$$6-x^2>1$$
and $x\ge0$ so I have the following interval:
$$[0,\sqrt5]$$
which contains 3 elements but the answer in my book is 7 so what am I missing here?
2) the interval for  x in order for the following expression to be true :
$$\log_x (x+1)+\log_{x^3}(x^3+1)=2\log_{x^2} 
(x^2+1)$$

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by the first part.

Comment: well my english is not very good,what I mean is I need to find an interval so that my radical exists.Now from what I know if I have a radical that looks like this $$\sqrt[n]{x} $$ n>1

Comment: And what do you mean by "the interval containing 3 elements?" 3 integers?

Comment: yes: 0,1,2 are the integers

Comment: What is your source for 1.? In 2., are you sure to be asked for an *interval*?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The function exists for $x>0$.

The limit for x tending to zero from the right is zero.

The limit for x tending to $\sqrt{6}$ from the left is infinite.

The limit for x tending to $\sqrt{6}$ from the right is null.

The limit for x tending to infinity is 1.

That is, it has a horizontal asymptotic, $y =1$.

The first derivative allows us to say that:

a)  In the path that goes from 0 to 1, the function is increasing, in $x=1$ has an inflection, and then grows to infinity for $x=\sqrt{6}$;

b)  In the path from $\sqrt{6}$ to an additional inflection point, the function is increasing, after the concavity is facing down to $x=$infinity, reaches the value 1. (horizontal asymptot).